# Cross compiling a software module

Tags: debian, c, arm, gnu, cross-compilation

I'm trying to compile [dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) with the GNU ARM tool chain. I've went through [this](http://bb.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/GnuArmToolchain) guide and managed to successfully build all the required tools.

They are located in a directory:

```
/home/tester/Misc/gnuarm/install
$ ls
arm-none-eabi  bin  include  lib  libexec  share
$ ls bin/
arm-none-eabi-addr2line  arm-none-eabi-c++filt  arm-none-eabi-gcc        arm-none-eabi-gcc-ranlib  arm-none-eabi-ld.bfd   arm-none-eabi-ranlib   arm-none-eabi-strip
arm-none-eabi-ar         arm-none-eabi-cpp      arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.8.2  arm-none-eabi-gcov        arm-none-eabi-nm       arm-none-eabi-readelf
arm-none-eabi-as         arm-none-eabi-elfedit  arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar     arm-none-eabi-gprof       arm-none-eabi-objcopy  arm-none-eabi-size
arm-none-eabi-c++        arm-none-eabi-g++      arm-none-eabi-gcc-nm     arm-none-eabi-ld          arm-none-eabi-objdump  arm-none-eabi-strings
$ ls lib/
gcc  libiberty.a
```

How may I configure dropbear to use GNU ARM tools upon build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is:

1. Add the compiler binaries to your path.

   ```
   export PATH="/home/tester/Misc/gnuarm/install/bin:$PATH"
   ```
2. Run `configure` in the Dropbear source directory with the correct options for cross-compiling.

   ```
   ./configure --host=arm-none-eabi
   ```
3. Continue compilation as per the `INSTALL` guide.

**Note:** If you do have any problems caused by the `--build` option being missing, you can add it. Just run `gcc -dumpmachine` to return the platform of your current build machine and then provide it as a parameter to `configure`.

For example, if `gcc -dumpmachine` returns `x86_64-linux-gnu` run

```
./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=arm-none-eabi
```

Comment: @StephenKitt Whoops, of course - corrected my answer

Comment: Just a quick question. How may I point configure to the ARM compiler tool chain? in the case when the path of the ARM binutils has not been exported.

Comment: @Sebi if the compiler knows where to find the rest of its required binaries (e.g., assembler, linker, etc) without them being in the path, you can set the `CC` environment variable when running `configure`.